# Android app architecture

Tags: android, web-services, communication, messaging

I am working on an Android app that will involve retrieving and submitting data from a server.  After retrieving the content the user will be able to perform certain operations and will submit some data back to the server.  In certain cases the data will be simply stored in the database, however sometimes I will need to do some processing of the data and then send back a notification to the app.

I am also trying to minimize the amount of data being transferred between the mobile app and server.  I am considering sending the mobile application a summary of the data available, instead of sending all of the data, and simply providing the user a way to request specific items from the summary.

Another concern I have is scalability, my initial thoughts were to put all the submitted data into a queue and process it from there.

What would be a good way about getting this done?  I am looking forward to all helpful comments.

Comment: You might have better luck asking specific questions that can be answered objectively. Check out the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a specific question in there, but I suspect your underlying need will be covered by [watching this 1hr video from Google IO 2010](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=xHXn3Kg2IQE). He covers in details different patterns for writing an Android app that hooks up to a remote server.

In general, you will almost certainly need to cache content locally, to reduce the bandwidth, CPU and battery usage on the device, and SQLite is probably a good place to put the data you have, grabbing more when you need it. But exactly how you implement it is going to depend a great deal on the specific requirements for your app.